# jQuery treetable: Get first and last child of all nodes

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, treetable

I have a TreeTable Api http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/#usage that I use to display my data from MySql in Html table.

What I am trying to do is OnDocumentReady in jQuery I need to disable some buttons.

[image]

This is my table structure It has 2 buttons on each row Move up and Move down.

In order to change the sequence of the tr I have created them. My problem is how could I get First child and Last child of each node so that I could disable move up button on first child and disable move down button on last child. And disable both buttons if a node has no siblings.

So far I have tried this but is not helping me

```
$('tr td:last-child').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this).contents(".md");
    $this.prop( "disabled", true );
});
$('tr td:last-child').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this).contents(".mu");
        $this.prop( "disabled", true );
});
```

.md(moveDown) and .mu(moveUp) are classes for buttons that will perform some database task when clicked later.

This is my HTML PHP code where I am processing the above table structure

```
<?php
include 'dbconn.php';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
    mysql_select_db('cms');
    //select all rows from the main_menu table
    $result = mysql_query("select id, label as title, parent as parentid,link,status from pages order by seq asc");
    //create a multidimensional array to hold a list of menu and parent menu
    $menu = array(
        'menus' => array(),
        'parent_menus' => array(),
    );
    //build the array lists with data from the menu table
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //creates entry into menus array with current menu id ie. $menus['menus'][1]
        $menu['menus'][$row['id']] = $row;
        //creates entry into parent_menus array. parent_menus array contains a list of all menus with children
        $menu['parent_menus'][$row['parentid']][] = $row['id'];
    }
    // Create the main function to build milti-level menu. It is a recursive function.  
    echo $html='<table class="test2 table  table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>Page Name</th>
                    <th> Status </th><th> Edit </th><th> Add Submenu </th><th><!--Delete Menu--></th><th> Sequence </th>
                </tr>
                <tr data-tt-id="0">
                    <td class="Root">Root</td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-info" onclick="addMenu(0,0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addmenu">
                        <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>Add</button></td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>';
    function buildMenu($parent, $menu) {
    $char=" ";
    if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$parent])) {
foreach ($menu['parent_menus'][$parent] as $menu_id) {
            //echo "id:".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id']."par:".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['parentid'];
              if($menu['menus'][$menu_id]['status']=='active')
              {
                  $class="btn-success";
                  $span="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign";
                  $set="";
              }
              else if($menu['menus'][$menu_id]['status']=='deactive')
                      {
                          $class="btn-danger";
                          $span="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign";
                          $set="disabled='disabled'";
                      }
                      else
                          {
                              $class="btn-info";

                          }
            if (!isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id])) {

                $html .= '<tr data-tt-id="'.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id'].'" data-tt-parent-id="'.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['parentid'].'">
                <td class="Root">'.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['title'].'</td>
                <td><button style="width:6em;" id="'.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id'].'" class="btn '.$class.'" 
                onclick="status('."'".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id']."'".",".
                "'".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['parentid']."'".","."'".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['status']."'".')">
                <span  class="'.$span.'"></span>'.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['status'].'</button>
                </td>

                <td><button id="'.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['title'].'" class="btn btn-warning setting dbbutton"  onclick="edit('.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id'].','.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['parentid'].')" '.$set.'>
                <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Edit</button>
                </td>

                <td><button class="btn btn-info" onclick="addMenu('.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id'].','.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['parentid'].')" 
                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addmenu">
                <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>Add</button>
                </td>

                <td><!--<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteMenu('.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id'].','.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['parentid'].')">
                <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete</button>--></td>             


                <td>    
                    <button id="'.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id'].'" class="btn btn-default btn-xs mu" onclick="moveUp(this)" style="color:orange !important;" title="Move Up">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top" ></span>
                    </button>
                    <button id="'.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id'].'" class="btn btn-default btn-xs md" onclick="moveDown(this)" style="color:orange !important" title="Move Down">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>
                </tr>'
                ;
            }
            if (isset($menu['parent_menus'][$menu_id])) {
                $html .= "<tr data-tt-id='".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id']."' data-tt-parent-id='".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['parentid']."'>
                            <td class='Root'>".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['title'];
                $html .= '</td>
                <td><button style="width:6em;" id="'.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id'].'" class="btn '.$class.'" onclick="status('."'".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id']."'".",".
                "'".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['parentid']."'".","."'".$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['status']."'".')">
                <span  class="'.$span.'"></span>'.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['status'].'</button>
                </td>

                <td><button id="'.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['title'].'"class="btn btn-warning setting dbbutton"  onclick="edit('.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id'].','.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['parentid'].')" '.$set.'>
                <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Edit</button>
                </td>

                <td><button class="btn btn-info" onclick="addMenu('.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id'].','.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['parentid'].')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addmenu">
                <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>Add</button>
                </td>

                <td><!--<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteMenu('.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id'].','.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['parentid'].')">
                <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete</button>--></td>

                <td>    
                    <button id="'.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id'].'" class="btn btn-default btn-xs mu" onclick="moveUp(this)" style="color:orange !important;" title="Move Up">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top" ></span>
                    </button>
                    <button id="'.$menu['menus'][$menu_id]['id'].'" class="btn btn-default btn-xs md" onclick="moveDown(this)" style="color:orange !important" title="Move Down">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span>
                    </button>
                </td>


                ';
                $html .= buildMenu($menu_id, $menu);
                //$html .= "</td>";
                $html .= "</tr>";
            }
        }
    }
    return $html;
}

echo buildMenu(0, $menu);

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: provide your html too

Comment: Sure but its actually in php will update it :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.find()` instead of `.contents()` to find the element with class `.md` in td. also you don't need to use `.each()`, you directly set the property to all of them:

```
$('tr td .md:last-child').prop( "disabled", true );
```

Comment: Thank You for your efforts Sir, but then all the elements with .md class are disabled.  :(

Comment: do you only want `.md` that are last child??

Comment: not working.. again the same issue.. I think probably the DOM is not able to interpret jQuery treetable structure. Its considering all the tr's as last child..

Comment: can you share the rendered html in fiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75477/discussion-between-steve-and-milind-anantwar).